# Creating a filter to compile a dynamic string in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi im new to angular JS and just getting to grips with it, Im trying to create a filter that will compile the given string that is stored in the database. The HTML is below which passes history.activity to my dynamic filter with :this appended to pass in the current scope.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="history in recentActivity">
    {{ history.activity | dynamic:this }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The history.activity variable contains a string in the format of an Angular template like below, these will vary as they are pulled in from the database based on the logged activity.

```
{{ history.username }} logged in at {{ history.created_date | date }}
```

My filter below is extremely basic and should compile the source but its just returning undefined.....

```
app.filter('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return function (source, scope) {
    return $compile(source)(scope);
  };
});
```

Any ideas? where am i going wrong with this? any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `activity` variable does not contain HTML but just angular expression then you need to use `$interpolate` instead of `$compile` - [check the angular.js docs for it](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate).

If you need to put some HTML dynamically then you need the directive as Jonathan said - filters cannot be used to include HTML.

But actually I'd like to suggest using directive anyway - both compilation/interpolation are relatively slow so it would be better to call them only when your expression is changed (which could be achived with `$watch` call inside directive). Filter expressions are called twice each digest cycle and you may meet performance problems if you'll use this filter often.

Answer (score 0):

When working with DOM, you'll need a directive.

```
<li ng-repeat="history in recentActivity" fun-times="history"></li>
```

And a directive:

```
app.directive("funTimes", function($compile){
   return{
     restrict: 'A',
     scope:{funTimes:'='},
     link: function(scope, element, attributes){
       scope.watch('funTimes', function(){              
         $compile(scope.funTimes)(scope, function(cloned, scope){ 
           element.html(cloned); 
         });
       });
     }
   }
}
```

I didn't test this, this is just off the top of my head.

Comment: I needed to change scope.watch to scope.$watch but now im getting the following error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {{ history.username }} logged in at {{ history.created_date | date }} any ideas?

Comment: As @GRaAL said, if you're not including HTML, use $interpolate instead of $compile.

Comment: A similar directive to this but using interpolate as your answer suggests worked at treat :)